# Submit jQuery form to Spring controller

Tags: jquery, spring, forms, http-post

I am trying to submit a form with jQuery form plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

my js looks like this:

```
var options = { 
        success: callback, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: url   
};
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
$('#myForm').submit();
```

my controller method looks like this:

```
public ModelAndView processForm(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
```

I am getting this error:

```
(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest) throws
 java.lang.Exception]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current 
request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a `MultipartResolver` configured in the spring configuration

Comment: @Arun Yes.  I have done this before with jquery.fileupload, but now I need to use something else.

Comment: In-fact, I have this in my applicationContext.     <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
    </bean>

Comment: which is the browser used? can you check it using IE < 10 and see whether it is working

Comment: I tried Chrome, FF, IE 11. Same error.  I do not have IE<10

Answer (score 1):

You can change your controller to handle both multipart and non-multipart

```
@RequestMapping(value="/urRequestMappingURL", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> controllingMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
        // process the uploaded file
    }
    else {
        // other logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of things: First, I need to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to the form tag.

also because the form tag spanned multiple divs, the jQuery form plugin did not pick up other inputs.  So i did this:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```

and then my js would use regular jQuery to add the other input fields before submiting like this:

```
    var options = { 
        success: callback, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: url,
        beforeSerialize: function(form, options) {
            options.data = {
                caseNo: $("#caseNo").val(),
                inspectionID: $("#inspectionID").val()
            };
        },
};
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Hope this helps someone